# Copy Offset of Range in With statement (Run-time error ‘438’)

Tags: excel, runtime-error, offset, with-statement, vba

I’m trying to write a program that will open two Excel books - in the first book search for certain data and insert it into another book in a certain place.

In a line

```
.r.Offset(, -27).Copy
```

Occurs an error

> Run-time error ‘438’ Object does’t support this property or method .

Code:

```
Sub грандэ()
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim book2 As Workbook
    Dim r As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B  As Long

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 7\Условия для андердогов\таблица.xlsm")
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 7\Условия для андердогов\1.xlsm")

    A = 29
    B = 10  

    With book1.Worksheets("таблица")

        For Each r In .Range("AC34:AC60").Rows
            If r.Value = 4 Or r.Value = 6 Then

                A = A + 1

                If A = 34 Then
                    B = B + 1
                    A = 30
                End If

                .r.Offset(, -27).Copy
                book2.Worksheets("Лист1").Cells(A, B).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

            End If
        Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Offset` returns a `Range` so you can chain `Copy`

Comment: Just omit the dot in front of r. It is already defined as a range on the sheet.

Comment: @SJR - I deleted my answer as it was blatantly wrong ;) You have the right answer re the unnecessary `.`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - we both fell into the same trap I think!

Comment: @SJR , Now all works . Thank you !